# Lack of Network Connection Checker Function in Python

Tags: python, urllib2

Are there any **technical** reasons why the `Python` urllib2 module doesn't provide a built-in function for checking if the network connection (the connection between the computer and the router) is present?

Comment: Please define "Internet connection". There's no such object as "Internet" to which you can connect.

Comment: As the first reply says, there's no such thing as an internet connection per se. How would you check? Ping to google.com? Visually check if you are connected to the WiFi?

Comment: What I was really referring to is the connection between a computer and the router. I am writing a `Python` script that'll run on a `Raspberry Pi` that's NOT connected to a monitor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The technical reason is that the name of the library is `urllib2`; it is a higher level library that those that would deal with the [network connectivity layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model#Description_of_OSI_layers).

Such lower level connectivity is provided by the operating system and thus most languages will plug into the networking library to find the status of a connection.

In reality what happens is, when you *establish* a connection, you application, its runtime and the operating system agree to do a *best effort attempt* to establish the connection.

Wherever the connection breaks (on the network layer) the piece of software responsible for that will propagate the error and eventually it will reach your **application runtime** which has to decide what to do with it.

It may chose to acknowledge it silently and retry; log it internally and provide you (the developer) a different message; or it may give you access to the low level error code directly.

In short, it cannot be practical for each higher level library to know the lower level connectivity details. There are lot of pieces to plug together to make the connection work; and they all work at different layer of the network model.

In order to really explore networking stack you'd have to use a lower-level library, like say [`sockets`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html); but then that is overkill if all you want to do is parse URLs.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to access some web site and if the "try" succeeds then you can get to the router. There may be other error codes that may be more specific.

```
rootUrl = 'http://www.dilbert.com'
try:
    webFile = urllib2.urlopen(rootUrl)
except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
    if e.code == 404:
        sys.exit("can't find:",rootUrl)
    else:
        print e
        sys.exit(rootUrl,"other error (not 404)")
```

Comment: I am aware of this solution, but I don't like to handle expected issues with an exception handler.

Comment: Using an exception handler for this would be the normal idiom in Python. [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp). Among other things it avoids race conditions: what if you check for an Internet connection, but it goes away by the time you try to get the URL?